# Polyhedra that combinatorially shadow a sequence

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, polyhedra

Let $P$ be a polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Say that $P$ *combinatorially shadows* a sequence of natural numbers $S$ if
there is a continuous rotation of $P$ such that its orthogonal-projection
shadows are polygons whose number of sides coincide with the elements of $S$
in order.  For example, $S$ might be the odd primes: $S=(3,5,7,11,13,\ldots)$,
and we want the shadows to be a triangle, then a pentagon, then a septagon,
then a hendecagon, etc.

**Q0**. Let $S$ be an increasing sequence of natural numbers,
whose first element is $\ge 3$.
Does there exist a polyhedron $P$ that combinatorially shadows $S$?

I think the answer here is *Yes*, illustrated just for $S=(3,5)$ with this
example:

      
[image: Polyhedron Shadows]

The generalization is that the needed increase above the previous element
in the sequence is achieved by bumping out near the centroid of an
appropriate face (the centroid $c$ 
of face $(1,2,3)$ in the
above example is bumped out to $\lbrace a, b \rbrace$),
shallow enough to be hidden for the previous element (middle image), but sufficent so
that a rotation will simultaneously expose the additional vertices (right image).
So if I am correct here, there is a *prime polyhedron* that realizes the odd primes—either
up to any given prime, or all odd primes if an infinite number of faces are countenanced.

*Correction* (*9Dec12*): I now think the above sketch fails to allow many vertices to appear in the shadow
simultaneously.  <strike>Better is to split existing vertices into two ...</strike>
[remaining bad idea deleted]. *23Dec12*: Now I believe the construction posted in a separate
answer settles **Q0** (positively).

My question concerns arbitrary—not necessarily increasing—sequences:

**Q1**. Let $S$ be an *arbitrary* sequence of natural numbers,
each $\ge 3$.
Does there exist a polyhedron $P$ that combinatorially shadows $S$?

Ideas, even half-baked, or pointers to relevant literature welcomed!  Thanks!

Comment: Try flowering.  Perhaps you can make the word picture work or say why it fails.  From one edge of the polyhedron, draw a semicircle.  Divide that semicircle into n_0 pieces, and use that for your first face.  For each of those n_0 edges, draw another semicircle (tilted away from the shadow projection, and perhaps translated so that each edge gets a rectangle followed by a semicircle) and repeat,dividing each semicircle into as many edges as necessary.  There are problems with this to be solved, but I do not see 2 as an obstacle.  Gerhard "After Two Comes Very Many" Paseman, 2012.12.13

Comment: @Gerhard: I have come to the same conclusion: doubling is not an obstacle. I also have been exploring an avenue akin to your idea. If/when time permits, I hope to eventually post an example. As always, thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 4):

This answers my **Q0**.
The polyhedron is the convex hull of these faces:

          
[image: Prime Polyhedron 17]

When rotated, the shadow has $3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17$ vertices:

          
[image: Prime Shadows]

Clearly the same
design (not dissimilar from Gerhard's suggestion)
suffices to capture any sequence with $s_{i+1}-s_i \ge 2$.
This suffices for a *prime polyhedron*, my original (recreational) goal.

          
[image: Prime Polyhedron 23]

It is not difficult to capture sequences that also sometimes increase by just $1$,
by arranging for rotation to expose a (thin) triangle face.
Thus the answer to **Q0** is *Yes*.